# How to prove that two determinant to be the same?

Tags: matrices

Given a covariance matrix $\Sigma \in R^{d \times d}$ and a full-rank matrix $W \in R^{d \times p} $ . 
Is that true that:

1. If $d=p$ then $\det( W^T \Sigma W) =\det (\Sigma) \det( W^T W)$
   Since I tried to run for several examples of $W$ and $\Sigma$ and the above equation is correct. However I do not know how to prove this ?
2. If $d>p$ how can we simplify $\det( W^T \Sigma W) $ so we can optimize $W$ easily for some optimization that involves $\det( W^T \Sigma W) $

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1.**

Remember that for square $A$ and $B$,

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B),$$

and then use the commutativity of multiplication.

**Part 2.**

Since $W$ isn't square in this case, you're probably going to need to find the gradient of:

$$f\circ g=\det(W^T\Sigma W),$$

where:

\begin{align}
g:\;{\bf R}^{dp}&\to{\bf R}^{p^2}\notag\\
W&\mapsto W^T\Sigma W\\\\
f:\;{\bf R}^{p^2}&\to{\bf R}\notag\\
A&\mapsto \det A.\notag
\end{align}